# how to make list as a parameter in the [GET, POST] methods

Tags: list, api, post, parameters, get

I'm working on a data set of 'Human activity recognition using smart phones'
would like to link the data with an API using flask, which can be reflected on a web page.
so I want to create a list to take all the human body movements in the data set as a parameters in a list which If I pass it to the predict route in the flask through a web page enables the model to predict the human body activity.

Answer (score 0):

Put the list in a JSON object. You can use `jsonify` for this.

```
@app.route('/get_fruits')
def get_fruits():
    response = {"fruits": ["apple", "banana"]}
    return jsonify(response)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt response, but the array has more than 1k attributes so how can I put them into a list as parameters?

Comment: HA.test_df.iloc[0,:].values                                                                                                                 array([0.25717778, -0.02328523, -0.014653761999999999,
       -0.9384040000000001, -0.92009078, -0.66768331, -0.95250112,
       -0.92524867, -0.67430222, -0.89408755, -0.55457721, -0.46622295,
       0.71720847, 0.6355024, 0.78949666, -0.87776423, -0.99776606,
       -0.99841381, -0.93434525, -0.97566897, etc till almost 1K

Comment: Is that a pandas dataframe? They have a ```.to_json``` function

Comment: Yes, it is a pandas dataframe, but I don't get this part "They have a .to_json function"  would you please tell me more ?